# Is there a way to have both the ability to use LaTeX commands and knitting an HTML document in R?

Tags: r

I want to write a small report in which I use the `amsmath` package to align several equations. Thing is, when I put it in the YAML preamble in RStudio, like this:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "BG"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
---
```

I cannot longer use kableExtra in order to make tables and have the output in HTML.

On the oposite side, if I want to use kableExtra I cannot knit in HTML, I have to do it in PDF, and then the tables don't look at all as I formated them. I guess I could use \begin{tabular}, but since I am working on a data frame, I want to take the data from there and create the table. And if I try to knit to HTML, I get the error

```
processing file: test.Rmd
  |.......................                             |  44% [unnamed-chunk-1]
Quitting from lines 18-19 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test.Rmd)
Error:
! package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
  call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% 
  error: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Backtrace:
 1. base::library(kableExtra)
 2. base::tryCatch(...)
 3. base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 4. base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5. value[[3L]](cond)
                                                                                                            
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Right now, it seems more like I either have the option to use kableExtra to create the tables (and to publish in HTML), or use the LaTeX packages.

Is there a way in which I can do both? I've been looking for this, but so far I haven't find anything.

I could use another package like `gt` I guess, but at this point it's more of something I must have, rather than to find an alternative, besides, I might just run into the same issue.